# [PointInfoController endAppearanceTransition]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x74d5e90

Tags: ios5, view, xcode4.2, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

I need a little help here, I've loaded a view by modal and basically I'm now trying to dismiss this view now but it keep crashing after the view goes.

It says *** -[PointInfoController endAppearanceTransition]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x74d5e90

### Below is the .H file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@class PointInfoController;

@protocol PointInfoDelegate
- (void)PointInfoDidFinish:(PointInfoController*)PointInfoController;
@end

@interface PointInfoController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnailView;

IBOutlet UIButton *Dismiss;

id<PointInfoDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (retain) id<PointInfoDelegate> delegate;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *description;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *thumbnailView;

- (IBAction)DismissView:(id)sender;


@end
```

### Below is the .M file:

```
#import "PointInfoController.h"
#import "LockOnLocation.h"

@implementation UIScrollView (AutoContentSize)

- (void) setAutosizeContent:(BOOL)autosizeContent {

if (autosizeContent) {
    CGFloat contentWidth =
    self.frame.size.width == self.superview.frame.size.width ?
    self.superview.frame.size.width :
    self.frame.size.width + 10;
    CGFloat contentHeight = 
    self.frame.size.height == self.superview.frame.size.height ?
    self.superview.frame.size.height :
    self.frame.size.height + 164;
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight);
}
}

@end

@implementation PointInfoController
@synthesize description;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize thumbnailView;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
}
*/

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.scrollView.delegate = self;

[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setDescription:nil];
[scrollView release];
scrollView = nil;
[self setScrollView:nil];
[self setThumbnailView:nil];
[thumbnailView release];
thumbnailView = nil;
[Dismiss release];
Dismiss = nil;

[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)DismissView:(id)sender
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)dealloc {
[description release];
[scrollView release];
[thumbnailView release];
[Dismiss release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to all this and I spent quite a few days on the same problem. Blamed everything but myself! I discovered I was inadvertently release(ing) the instance referred to. In my case I had put the instance into a SSLConnectionRef and CFRelease'd it. I'm not sure why you are having the issue looking at your code. In any event, I thought your compiler would complain about your [instance release] methods, since these are no longer allowed. You are having the problem because both you and the system are releasing the instance. You need to get rid of your release and all will be well.